# How many times in Cricket Test Match have scored Four runs by running across the Wicket. Not as Boundaries?

Tags: cricket, trivia

Also which Team scored Fours runs in a delivery by running the most time? and who all are the players scored the same for most times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not a very common occurrence, this phenomenon does feature quite a lot in test matches (especially on the bigger grounds like in Australia or England). Hence, there is almost no extra media attention whenever this occurs.

Also, ball-by-ball information is not available for a substantial amount of test matches. Hence there is almost no way of answering your question quantitatively.